# I need to move column's data to another column within the same table.

Tags: sql

I need to move column's data to another column within the same table.

Can anybody tell me how to write this?

Comment: Please tag which flavour of SQL you are using (eg, mySQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, PostgreSql, et)

Comment: Show us some sample table data, versions both before and after the move.

Comment: MS SQL Server. update table
set NewColumn = OldColumn;

update table
set OldColumn = null;

Comment: with this code, columns gets same value to another columns

Comment: I need to all the data in two columns are in one comumn

Comment: Not clear with your last statement.

Comment: `update foo set one_column = other_column`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET NewColumn = OldColumn;

UPDATE table SET OldColumn = null;
```

Comment: You don't need two updates for that, `update foo set NewColumn = OldColumn, oldcolumn = null` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax may vary depending on SQL flavour

```
update table
set NewColumn = OldColumn;

update table
set OldColumn = null;
```

Comment: You don't need two updates for that, `update foo set NewColumn = OldColumn, oldcolumn = null` will work just fine.